# Option selected for dynamic option populated from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am getting a value from an ajax response. The ajax code is given below:

```
success:function(response)
      {
        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
         html='';
         html+='<option value="">Select&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;سثمثؤف</option>';
         $.each(obj,function(i,val){
            var str="{{collect(old('eng_area'))}}";
            str=str.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
            str=parseInt(str, 10);
            vv=val.id;

           html+='<option value='+val.id+' ('+str+'=='+vv+') ? "selected" : "">'+val.area_eng+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+val.area_arb+'</option>';
         })
        $('#eng_area').html(html);

    }
```

Here I store the value in the `str` and `vv` variables. I want the option to be selected when both variables have the same value. For this I tried:

```
('+str+'=='+vv+') ? "selected" : ""
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here - is there any other solution for this ??

Comment: Did you declare html and vv as a variable outside your success?

Comment: No its inside the success function

Comment: Every thing is working fine but the condition which i added ('+str+'=='+vv+') ? "selected" : "" not working properly is there any other way to wrote it ??

Comment: try `'+val.id+(str==vv) ? "selected" : ""+'>'`

Comment: Not working ....

Comment: You are doing a major mistake here. There is no need of putting the == in strings as you don't need to escape it.
Try
    (str == vv)

Comment: you place condtion as string. you can do that like this `'<option value="' + val.id + '" ' + ((str == vv) ? 'selected' : 'asd') + '>' + val.area_eng + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + val.area_arb + '</option>'`

Comment: Thanx @shajji Its working now thax alot...